# How do I write to a conditional output

Tags: chisel

In my code I have defined a conditional output:

```
class EccGenerate[D <: Data](data: D, doubleBit : Boolean = true) extends Module {
  val eccBits = calcCodeBits(data.getWidth)

  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(data.cloneType)
    val out = Output(UInt(eccBits.W))
    val par = if (doubleBit) Some(Output(Bool())) else None
  })
```

Trying to use the := operator on the par output fails, because it is not always an output.  When using conditional inputs, I would use io.par.get() to retrieve the current value of the input, is there a corresponding primitive, operator or function call I can use to set the value of a conditional output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you can't connect to `par` because it's type is `Option[Bool]` and `:=` isn't define for `Option`. You need to unpack it and assign to the `Bool` inside if the option contains something.

The functional programming way of doing this would be:

```scala
io.par.foreach(_ := foo)
```

You can also be more verbose about it if you want:

```scala
io.par match {
  case Some(a) => a := foo
  case None    =>
}
```

An `if` statement would also work:

```scala
if (par.nonEmpty) {
  io.par.get := foo
}
```

Comment: jinx, you owe me a coke

Comment: Deal. For more context: Jack and I wrote basically the exact same answer. I happened to be writing it on my phone. My answer clocked in 3 minutes later, but Guy gave me the accepted answer. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ For posterity: there's independent agreement that this is the correct way to do a connection to an optional Chisel component.

Answer (score 4):

You basically need to check if `io.par` is `Some` or `None`, there are several ways to do this:

1. Imperatively

```scala
if (io.par.isDefined) {
  io.par.get := ...
}
```

2. Pattern Matching

```scala
io.par match {
  case Some(port) => port := ...
  case None => // Do nothing
}
```

3. Functional Programming (ish)

```scala
io.par.foreach(_ := ...)
```

I tend to prefer #2 or #3 depending on what I'm doing, but #1 may be more clear to people less familiar with Scala and Functional Programming.

For more information, check out the API Docs for Option: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.10/scala/Option.html