# Using Parameters to declare variable-sized Vec

Tags: chisel

I'm trying to have a variable-sized array based on a Module Paramete (example below). When the size PARAM is non-zero, the code works as intended.

```
class HWModule (PARAM : Int) extends Module{

    val my_Vec = RegInit(Vec(Seq.fill(PARAM)(0.U(32.W)))) 

    if (PARAM > 0){
        for (i <- 0 until PARAM -1){        
            my_Vec(i) := i.U //Example Code
        }     
    }
}
```

However, when I try to have PARAM = 0, it stops working. I've tried using Patter Matching ([How do I write to a conditional output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234116/how-do-i-write-to-a-conditional-output)) to solve the problem, but I get the following error messages (and similar ones):

> Equals does not take parameters

> Expression does not convert to assignment because receiver is not assignable.

My goal is to be able to remove certain portions of code when PARAM = 0, while also allowing to variable-sized instantiation of Vecs, Regs, Wires, etc.
If anyone could point me to a good solution or information about it, I would appreciate it.

Thank you,
Miguel Silva

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Option` like this :

```
val my_Vec_or_none = if(PARAM > 0) Some(RegInit(Vec(Seq.fill(PARAM))(0.U(32.W)))) else None
```

Then get register with `get` method :

```
    if (PARAM > 0){
        val my_Vec = my_Vec_or_none.get
        for (i <- 0 until PARAM -1){        
            my_Vec(i) := i.U //Example Code
        }     
    }
```

Also you can use indexed value directly (without intermediate `val`) :

```
val my_Vec = if(PARAM > 0) Some(RegInit(Vec(Seq.fill(PARAM))(0.U(32.W)))) else None

if (PARAM > 0){
    for (i <- 0 until PARAM -1){        
        my_Vec.get(i) := i.U //Example Code
    }     
}
```

And use this variable in another part of the code.

Comment: That results in the following error: "value get is not a member of Equals"

Also, I believe that solution would limit the scope of my_Vec. I need to use that variable in other parts of the code.

But thanks.

Comment: Sorry, there was a `Some()` forgotten. I edited the code and added some `get` explanation.